# Did a man in France sue his employer because he was bored at work?

Tags: work, lawsuits, court-case

According to this [article](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/05/05/this-man-sued-his-employer-for-400000-because-he-was-bored-at-work.html), a man from France sued his employer for $400,000 because he was bored at work.

The article also states:

> He was later fired after a car crash caused him to go on prolonged
>   sick leave.

It sounds like the reason might have been different. The article doesn't mention if he actually won the case either. So what is the truth because it sounds a little unbelievable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This article](http://www.lemonde.fr/emploi/article/2016/05/03/frederic-desnard-veut-se-faire-le-porte-voix-du-bore-out_4913054_1698637.html), from the French newspaper Le Monde, explains that Mr Desnard was fired because of his prolonged sick leave due to his car accident. He is suing because he contests his dissmissal.
His physician said that the epiliptic seizure that caused the accident may have been caused by his extreme boredom, but no one else said so.
The court decision will be published in July.

Comment: Extreme boredom causing epileptic seizures is something new to me. This seems to be a claim to be challenged on the site by itself!

Comment: What was the decision by the court?